# Mapping from EF entities to gRPC Protobuf messages

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, grpc

I've started experimenting with gRPC and I would like to be able to map my db entities to protobuf messages using automapper. But I can't figure out how to map the repeated fields.

My message definitions looks like this:

```
message WorklistResponse {
    repeated WorklistMessage Worklists = 1;
}

message WorklistMessage {
    int32 WorklistId = 1;
    repeated CollectionWorkMessage Work = 2;
}

message CollectionWorkMessage {
    int32 WorkId = 1;
    string AddressComment = 2;
}
```

And I'm trying to map from an entity that looks like this:

```
[Table("Worklist")]
public sealed class DbWorklist
{
    public DbWorklist()
    {
        Work = new HashSet<DbWork>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int WorklistId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DbWork> Work { get; set; }
}
```

Where the related entities DbWork is an abstract baseclass to DbCollectionWork and look like this:

```
[Table("Work")]
public abstract class DbWork
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public int WorklistId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(WorklistId))]
    public DbWorklist Worklist { get; set; }
}

public sealed class DbCollectionWork : DbWork
{
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string AddressComment { get; set; }
}
```

I have two mappings configured:

```
cfg.CreateMap<DbWorklist, WorklistMessage>();
cfg.CreateMap<DbCollectionWork, CollectionWorkMessage>();
```

I can do this:

```
var worklists = dbContext.Worklists.Include(wl => wl.Work).ToList();
var worklistWork = autoMapper.Map<List<CollectionWorkMessage>>(worklists[0].Work);

var worklistResponse = new WorklistResponse
{
    Worklists = { new WorklistMessage
    {
        Work = { worklistWork }
    }}
};
```

This seems to be the only way I can set the Work property which is a protobuf3  `RepeatedField<CollectionWorkMessage>` that becomes a read-only property in the autogenerated protobuf class.

I would like to be able to construct my message using automapper.

I'm using AutoMapper 8.0, Grpc 1.19.0, Protobuf 3.7.0 and EF Core 2.2.4